# Creating besopoke 3rd party authoirsation for .net core without Identiy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, razor, oauth

I'm trying to set up .net core site which is part of a much bigger legacy system written in another language. I don't want to rewrite the login / authorisation for the main system at this stage, so I need users to be able to login via the main system and pass their logged in credentials and authorisation roles into the new .net system.

I don't want to maintain a separate user database within the new system, so will use the old system as a 3rd party authentication service effectively. I'm struggling to find examples of the best way to achieve this. I'm imagining that I can write an OAuth process between the two systems.

I basically want the new system to check with the old system if someone is logged in with permission to access, if so then let them contiune, and if not bounce them back to the old system to login.

Is the best thing to use [Cookie Authentication without identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on the new site, and somehow write into that a redirect / OAuth process to the legacy system? Does anyone know of any examples or guidelines on how to do this? All I've been able to find are examples of linking to a preset list of third-party providers (i.e. google, facebook etc).

I'm ok with writing the OAuth part on the old system, just not sure how to implement it on the .net  core site side. As always, any guidance very much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, asp.net core contains the OAuth 2.0 Authentication Middleware which could work with oauth.

More details about how to use it, you could refer to below example:

Notice: It seems you used your owin authentication server, you should replace the parameter by yourself.

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // If an authentication cookie is present, use it to get authentication information
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                // If authentication is required, and no cookie is present, use Yourauth (configured below) to sign in
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Yourauth";
            })
 .AddCookie() // cookie authentication middleware first
 .AddOAuth("Yourauth", options =>
 {
    // Oauth authentication middleware is second

    var Domain = Configuration.GetValue<string>("yourdomain");

    // When a user needs to sign in, they will be redirected to the authorize endpoint
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"{Domain}/oauth2/default/v1/authorize";

    // if your OAuth server is OpenID compliant, so request the standard openid
    // scopes when redirecting to the authorization endpoint
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
     options.Scope.Add("profile");
     options.Scope.Add("email");

    // After the user signs in, an authorization code will be sent to a callback
    // in this app. The OAuth middleware will intercept it
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/authorization-code/callback");

    // The OAuth middleware will send the ClientId, ClientSecret, and the
    // authorization code to the token endpoint, and get an access token in return
    options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
     options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
     options.TokenEndpoint = $"{Domain}/oauth2/default/v1/token";

    // Below we call the userinfo endpoint to get information about the user
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = $"{Domain}/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo";

    // Describe how to map the user info we receive to user claims
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
     options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "given_name");
     options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");

     options.Events = new OAuthEvents
     {
         OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
         {
            // Get user info from the userinfo endpoint and use it to populate user claims
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
             request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
             request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

             var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
             response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

             var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

             context.RunClaimActions(user);
         }
     };
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for this pointer - sorry for the delay in response, I'm just working through a few things to see if I can get it to work, then I'll update here to verify!

Comment: Yes - this worked great in the end, thank you. I replaced 'var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());' with 'var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).RootElement;' to use System.Text.Json in .net5. I also changed the 'yourdomain' and 'ClientID' etc to be 'Yourauth:yourdomain' etc so it would read those variables from a 'Yourauth' entry in the appsettings.json file.